# Issue with many-to-many relationship + TPH inhertitance in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-6, table-per-hierarchy

I am running into an issue with EF6, though I'm fairly sure that this applies to previous versions that support this type of mapping. I fear I know the answer to the question at hand, but I hope that I am doing something wrong, or there is a better workaround than what I present here. All classes are gutted for clarity.

So I have

```
public abstract class SoftwareFirmware
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<DeviceType> DeviceTypes { get; private set; } 

    public SoftwareFirmware()
    {
        DeviceTypes=new HashSet<DeviceType>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DeviceType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Firmware> AvailableFirmwareVerions { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Software> AvailableSoftwareVerions { get; private set; }

    public DeviceType()
    {
        AvailableFirmwareVerions = new HashSet<Firmware>();
        AvailableSoftwareVerions = new HashSet<Software>();
    }
}
```

which as you can see have a many to many relationship defined. I've defined two classes which derive from `SoftwareFirmware`, the aptly named

```
public class Firmware : SoftwareFirmware {}
```

and

```
public class Software : SoftwareFirmware {}
```

I'm using Table Per Hierarchy inheritance, so `Software` and `Firmware` are stored in the same table with a discriminator column. Finally, I've mapped the relationships in the derived `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceType>().HasMany(d => d.AvailableFirmwareVerions).WithMany(firmware=>firmware.DeviceTypes);
modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceType>().HasMany(d => d.AvailableSoftwareVerions).WithMany(sofware=>sofware.DeviceTypes);
```

The problem at hand is that Entity Framework does not seem to support inheritance with this mapping, as I receive the following when EF tries to generate the database:

> DeviceTypes: FromRole: NavigationProperty 'DeviceTypes' is not valid.
>   Type 'Software' of FromRole
>   'DeviceType_AvailableSoftwareVerions_Target' in AssociationType
>   'DeviceType_AvailableSoftwareVerions' must exactly match with the type
>   'SoftwareFirmware' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.

From this I gather that a type that inherits from `SoftwareFirmware` is not good enough for the NavigationProperty, it must be a `SoftwareFirmware` type. If I tear the `DeviceType` collection out of the `SoftwareFirmware` base class and duplicate it in each of the derived classes, things work, but that's certainly less than ideal.

So finally, my question is- is there another way to configure this so that I can keep my navigation property in my base class? If not, is there a cleaner workaround than what I've described?

---

**UPDATE:** so it would seem that SQL Server Management Studio did me wrong, as I had diagrammed out the database previously without the overloaded version of WithMany that takes an expression and it did not include the junction tables. It seems like SSMS doesn't play nice with schema changes in terms adding new diagramming even when the database has been dropped and recreated- it must be restarted. Major pain, but I digress...

As a last ditch effort, I reverted to the parameterless version of `WithMany` for the mappings, deleted and recreated the database by restarting the application, restarted SSMS, and lo! The junction tables were created. All I needed to do is add an `Ignore` for the base `SoftwareFirmware` class's `DeviceTypes` property and everything generated cleanly. So my FluentAPI mapping code looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceType>().HasMany(d => d.AvailableFirmwareVerions).WithMany();
modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceType>().HasMany(d => d.AvailableSoftwareVerions).WithMany();
modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareFirmware>().Ignore(s => s.DeviceTypes);
```

which generates this schema- pretty much exactly the schema I wanted (ignore the extra properties):

[image]

However, since the parameterless call to `WithMany` only hooks up a navigation property on one side, updates to `Software.DeviceTypes` and `Firmware.DeviceTypes` aren't tracked by EF so I'm back where I started.

Comment: _previous versions_ Do you mean you switched from database-first (edmx) to code-first?

Comment: @GertArnold no, as in EF versions 5 and earlier. I'm not sure when what features were added, but I would imagine this applies to 5 and 4 as well, maybe earlier. I've noticed that an inordinate portion of EF questions do not reference a version number. This leads to confusion when someone stumbles across them a version or so later and the chosen answer is no longer relevant or the problem no longer exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have a single SoftwareFirmware.DeviceTypes property but you are then trying to use it as part of two separate relationships. SoftwareFirmware.DeviceTypes can't be the inverse of both DeviceType.AvailableFirmwareVerions and DeviceType.AvailableSoftwareVerions.

What you're trying to model is a bit strange because you're kind of treating them as distinct relationships, but also not. There are two options here...

**Option 1: It's two separate relationships**

Remove SoftwareFirmware.DeviceTypes and add a DeviceTypes property on Firmware and Software.

This is actually what you are doing when you put Ignore on the SoftwareFirmware.DeviceTypes property and use the empty overload of WithMany - which is why it works. You're telling EF that there are two relationships (one Software -> DeviceType and the other Firmware -> DeviceType) and that there is no navigation property that points back the other way. Since you ignored SoftwareFirmware.DeviceTypes it's just not part of your model.

**Option 2: It's one relationship**

Remove the two navigation properties on DeviceType and replace them with a single navigation to the SoftwareFirmware base class. You can always add some façade properties that filter the contents to Software and Firmware (as shown below)

```
public class DeviceType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SoftwareFirmware> AvailableVerions { get; private set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Firmware> AvailableFirmwareVerions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.AvailableVerions.OfType<Firmware>();
        }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Software> AvailableSoftwareVerions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.AvailableVerions.OfType<Software>();
        }
    }

    public DeviceType()
    {
        AvailableVerions = new HashSet<SoftwareFirmware>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup I see what you're saying. I think this is one of those situations where I should have stepped away from the keyboard long before I did.

Answer (score 3):

This problem sounds familiar. (checking my email ...yep it was over a year ago!) I had someone send me a sample where a fluent api relationship was failing. They did not have a many to many but I think it's the same problem. I spent a long time looking at it and asked Rowan Miller (on the team) and he said that the fluent api can't comprehend the property coming from the base type.

i.e. the fluent API can't see the DEVICETYPE property when it's looking at AvailableSoftwareVerions or at AvailableFirmwareVersions. (I can't tell you WHY this is. You'd think it could find it via reflection but maybe it just wasn't designed with this scenario in mind.)

This still didn't make sense to me so he explained further (and I'll update his explanation with your types which was a little confusing since you have extra levels of inheritance and things are named a bit inconsistently ...but I

> Conceptually the classes don’t really make sense, because a DeviceType
>   can have many Software(s) or Firmware(s)… but the inverse navigation property is
>   defined on SoftwareFirmware. So what happens when something that isn’t
>   a Firmware or Software has a DeviceType? It’s inverse is configured as > DeviceType.AvailableSoftwareVersions
>   but that can’t work. Even taking EF out of the picture the correct way
>   to model that is to have the Project property be on Report.

That was with EF5. If my memory is correct and it's the same problem, then maybe it hasn't changed for EF6. Perhaps we should look to see if there's an issue in there for solving this problem. However, his further explanation suggests that it's not a bug but a protection.

(I'm going to ping him to verify that I'm inferring the previous problem to this one correctly).

In that email, Rowan also suggested using getter logic instead of a navigation properties as a workaround.

Comment: I think your quote got a little muddled in translation but this is pretty much what I had figured while hoping I was wrong. Conceptually, it seems that this explanation starts to cross the boundary into composition vs inheritance, or maybe I've just been thinking of inheritance in OOP the wrong way all these years. Should make for a good question on [Programmers.StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: new info, updated question. Seems to go against what Rowan said.

Comment: I can only say <shrug> without rolling my sleeves up and spending some time experimenting with this. Hopefully (and highly likely that) Rowan can explain off the top of his head.